# The very first living organism model

Tags: life

Can you advice me where I can find explanation, what was the very first living organism on Earth? I am looking for nicely explained material, preferably with some 3d models and animation, showing how it could work. Maybe a computer emulation?

The sources I was able to find so far were very theoretical and dry, they didn't allow me to get a good grasp on the concept. Basically I am looking for the simplest living organism possible in order to get a good grasp on the mechanics of life.

From the sources I studied so far I understood that it was just a molecule of RNA, which could copy itself, right? But I didn't find exact description how it could look like..

Comment: Not the first living organism, but [Julia Child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Child) on how to make primordial soup: [video](https://massasoit.instructure.com/courses/346438/pages/video-the-primordial-soup-with-julia-child)

Comment: Nobody knows for sure -- there are many theories, tending to be quite general. "RNA world" is indeed one theory, but there are others. You will become quite celebrated and famous if you end up providing an answer for your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thermodynamically, how did the first cell arise?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/101691/thermodynamically-how-did-the-first-cell-arise)

Comment: @Armand Haha, yes! After asking the question I found out that nobody got an idea what was the earliest self-replicating structure in the first place. And I wanted to see a nice simple model of it!

Comment: @Luigi Not quite, but it is an interesting information. I wanted a visual easy to understand model of the first structure that could replicate itself. But it seems that it is yet unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamemtal basis of establishing something as living is the capability of replication and producing copies of forms similar to itself. Therefore, something which has two properties  i.e to act as enzyme and information carrier at the same time can perform that function and qualify to be called as first living *(but we will call it first living system or molecule not first living organism some say so, there are many arguments, depending upon how they look upon something to be called as living, it is itself a big question but it seems strongly persuasive that something like RNA world model is surely first form of life) This system is self perpetuating(heredity is basis of evolution and this is basically  heredity). If you want the story behind how it was done and quench your thirst (its short read) I'm giving the link below
https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/01/090109173205.htm

After you'll read that It was not easy to make this cross replicating system. And get that result to establish grounds of RNA world.